# How to display incorrect answers using html/php/mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a query below where it displays the correct answer per question in an exam:

```
<?

        $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, q.QuestionId an.Answer
        FROM Session s
        INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
        JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
        AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
        WHERE s.SessionName = "XULWQ"
        ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
       ";

       // prepare query
       $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
       // You only need to call bind_param once
       $stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment);
       // execute query
       $stmt->execute(); 


           // This will hold the search results
        $searchQuestionId = array();
        $searchAnswer = array();

        // Fetch the results into an array

       // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
       $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbQuestionId, $dbAnswer);
          while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            $searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
            $searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;

          } 

    ?>
```

Below is the result is outputs from the query:

```
SessionId  QuestionId  Answer
137        1           B
137        1           D
137        1           F
137        2           A
137        2           C
```

Now I have stored the data above in a php/html table using code below:

```
<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$row_span = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
$prev_ques = '';
foreach($searchQuestionId as $key=>$questionId){

?>

<tr class="questiontd">
    <?php
    if($questionId != $prev_ques){
    ?>
    <td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo$questionId?>_qnum" name="numQuestion" rowspan="<?php echo$row_span[$questionId]?>">
    <?php echo$questionId?> 
    </td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
<td class="answertd" name="answers[]"><?php echo$searchAnswer[$key]?><input type='hidden' id='hidanswerid' name='answersId[]' value='<?php echo$searchAnswerId[$key]?>'></td>
</tr>
<?php
$prev_ques = $questionId;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The output of the html/php table:

[image]

So you can see I outputted a table where it contains the correct answers per question in that exam. Great. But now I want to create another page
which is similar but this time except displaying the correct answers per question, I want it to display the incorrect answers per question.

I am not sure what is best way to do it but my plan I believe is to first retrieve the option_type for each question (option type is the number of options to select an answer from):

Query:

```
 $query="SELECT q.SessionId, q.QuestionId, o.OptionId
    FROM SESSION s
    INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
    JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
    WHERE s.SessionName = "XULWQ"
    ORDER BY q.QuestionId";
```

Result:

```
SessionId   QuestionId OptionId
137         1              5
137         2              2
```

Then use a case statement in php to display the letters for each case (need help coding this):

E.g

```
case 1, OptionId = 1, letters = A B C
case 2, OptionId = 2, letters = A B C D
case 3, OptionId = 3, letters = A B C D E

... //continue going down

case 26, OptionId = 26, letters = A B C D E ... Z
case 27, OptionId = 27, letters = True False (Options True or False)
case 28, OptionId = 28, letters = Yes or No (Options Yes or No)
```

Then some how remove the correct answers from the letters (maybe using query but I am not sure) so the html/php table contains all the incorrect answers rather than the correct answers in the table

So my question is how can it be coded in order to display the incorrect answers rather than the correct answer in the html/php table?

The output of the html/php table from the example above should look like this:

[image]

Comment: You can exchange the answers among questions while printing.

Comment: use array_diff to get the incorrect answers.  $leters=A,B,C,D; $correct_ans=B,D; $incorrect_ans=array_diff($letters,$correct_ans);

Comment: @Kirtan if you can provide me an answer showing where and what the code page should look like, I will be very happy and mark your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the options in an array

```
$option[1]= array(A,B,C);  
$option[2]= array(A,B,C,D);  
$option[3]= array(A,B,C,D,E);  
.  
.  
.  
.  
$option[27]= array(True,False);
```

Retrieve the option_type from the database same as u did.

Query:

```
$query="SELECT q.SessionId, q.QuestionId, o.OptionId
FROM SESSION s
INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
WHERE s.SessionName = "XULWQ"
ORDER BY q.QuestionId";
```

Result:

```
SessionId   QuestionId OptionId
137         1              5
137         2              2
```

foreach  QuestionId

```
$incorrect_ans[QuestionId]=array_diff($option[OptionId],$correct_ans[QuestionId]);
```

Comment: And to store it in html table is it simply: `<td class="answertd" name="incorrectanswers[]"><?php echo$incorrect_ans[QuestionId][$key]?></td>`

Comment: yes. foreach QuestionID there is an array of incorrect answer.

Comment: Thanks I will go ahead with it :)